# Texture that only effects faces that are facing upwards

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Does anyone know how to apply a texture in Cycles that only effects the faces of a mesh that are facing upwards (ie in the global Z direction within an angular tolerance)?

This would be very useful for snow, frost, dirt or dust.

I've done some experiments using the Tangent node but the results are not ideal.

I believe Maya has a snow texture that produces this type of result.

Comment: You should accept this answer if it was helpful, and don't confuse your accounts.

Answer (score 13):

Use this node setup for your material:

[image: Material nodes]

The dot product of the face normal with vector *(0, 0, 1)* is 0 when the face normal is orthogonal (= horizontal) and maximal when equal. When pointing downwards the dot product is negative.

With the color ramp you can control the angular tolerance. If you don't want to have a smooth transition between texture and green you can move white handle to the black one.

This is used as the factor of a Mix Shader mixing the texture with a green diffuse material.

Result:
[image: Render result]

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from Maccesch, helped me a lot, thanks. Alternatively, you can use the greater than operator if you want a hard separation. In the example below, only faces that are facing (i.e. their normal has same direction as) the x-axis:

[image: example using greater than]